# ¿Por qué se dice "teléfono móvil" y no "portátil" o "movible", pero para el ordenador se dice "ordenador portátil" pero no "móvil" o "movible"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras, españa, adjetivos, informática

[**Móvil**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PxcFux4) es:

> 1. adj. Que puede moverse o se mueve por sí mismo. U. t. c. s.

[**portátil**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Tl21X5Z) es:

> 1. adj. Movible y fácil de transportar.

y

[**movible**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PxNNmcd) es:

> 1. adj. Que por sí puede moverse, o es capaz de recibir movimiento por ajeno impulso.

Son, por tanto, tres adjetivos cuyo significado se solapa en gran medida.

¿Por qué se elige uno frente a otro? ¿Por qué se dice **teléfono móvil** y no **portátil** o **movible**, mientras que para el ordenador se dice **ordenador portátil** pero no **móvil** o **movible**? Ahora que los teléfonos son cada vez más grandes y potentes, ya casi ordenadores, ¿cambiará la terminología?

Nota: soy consciente que en muchos sitios se utiliza teléfono **celular** en vez de **móvil**.

Comment: En Colombia sencillamente se usa la palabra "celular" para referirse a un aparato telefónico apto para telefonía móvil celular (y de hecho hablamos de empresas de celulares, tarifa de celulares, etc) y "portátil" para referirse a lo que en inglés denominan "laptop".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El caso es que, durante sus primeros años de vida (años 70 y principios de los 80), ambos términos estuvieron por así decirlo "peleando", tal como puede verse en [estos resultados de Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tel%C3%A9fono%20m%C3%B3vil%2Ctel%C3%A9fono%20port%C3%A1til&year_start=1970&year_end=1990&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctel%C3%A9fono%20m%C3%B3vil%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctel%C3%A9fono%20port%C3%A1til%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

Esto es porque "teléfono portátil" ya se estaba usando desde principios del siglo XX para referirse a aparatos telefónicos que, si bien podían transportarse con relativa facilidad, seguían dependiendo del cable para hacer la llamada. En [estos resultados de búsqueda](https://www.google.es/search?biw=1600&bih=769&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1900%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1980&tbm=bks&ei=FzQdWsCHEcOtU4SluqAD&q=%22tel%C3%A9fono%20port%C3%A1til%22&oq=%22tel%C3%A9fono%20port%C3%A1til%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...201490.204113.0.204425.6.5.1.0.0.0.135.377.4j1.5.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.GPGUMot83ng) hay muchos ejemplos de uso, pero cito solamente un par:

> **Teléfono portátil para bomberos.**—El concejo del condado de Londres ha provisto al cuerpo de bomberos metropolitano, de un teléfono portátil que ciertamente constituye un progreso (...)
>
> <sub>*Caras y caretas*, 1903.</sub>
>
> ---
>
> *(En efecto, la Camarera ha vuelto a aparecer, trayendo un teléfono portátil con cable y clavija de enchufe.)*
>   INTÉRPRETE. — *(Cogiéndole el teléfono.)* Please... *(Se agacha y mete la clavija del teléfono en un enchufe que hay debajo de la mesa.)*
>
> <sub>Enrique Jardiel Poncela, 1965.</sub>
>
> ---
>
> **Teléfono portátil**
>   Standard Eléctrica ha lanzado un teléfono portátil que permite una clara conversación a distancias superiores a 30 kilómetros. Es un aparato autónomo, con tres pilas de linterna. Utiliza dos hilos, pero puede ir con uno y retornar por tierra.
>
> <sub>*Economista: Revista Semanal Científica E Independiente*, Volumen 80, Parte 2, 1968.</sub>

Es normal por tanto que, al principio, se intentase usar el mismo término para los nuevos teléfonos "sin hilos".
Pero era una terminología condenada al fracaso: [el término *"mobile phone"* fue siempre el más usado en inglés](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mobile%20phone%2Cportable%20phone&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1970&year_end=1990&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cmobile%20phone%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmobile%20phone%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMobile%20Phone%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMobile%20phone%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMOBILE%20PHONE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cportable%20phone%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bportable%20phone%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPortable%20Phone%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

Se comprende que al final, por influencia del inglés *"mobile phone"*, en español haya prevalecido "teléfono móvil" por encima de "teléfono portátil" o "teléfono movible".

También influye el hecho de que en los 80 empezó a usarse "portátil" para denominar a los novedosos ordenadores portátiles, por lo que habría resultado harto confuso llamar también "portátil" a los teléfonos móviles.

---

Por cierto, que revisando los resultados del primer enlace, puede verse que no eres el primero que se plantea esta cuestión:

> *Móvil* se dice de un teléfono que permite una comunicación a larga distancia entre personas sin que el aparato telefónico esté sujeto o tenga hilos imprescindibles, hasta hace relativamente poco, para establecer la conexión.
>
> Tal y como queda definido no se contempla en ninguna de las acepciones del diccionario de la Academia. Lo más similar se encuentra en la sexta acepción: *(Física) Cuerpo en movimiento*. (Evidentemente el teléfono portátil, ese al que se denomina generalmente *móvil*, es un cuerpo en movimiento, aunque más exacto sería escribir un cuerpo movido).
>
> <sub>Julio Bernárdez, [*El deporte correctamente hablado*](https://books.google.es/books?id=81cKNi2SghcC&lpg=PT17&dq=%22tel%C3%A9fono%20port%C3%A1til%22&hl=es&pg=PT17#v=onepage&q=%22tel%C3%A9fono%20port%C3%A1til%22&f=false), 1998.</sub>

Comment: Jardiel Poncela murió en 1952, por lo que la fecha de la cita debe estar errada

Comment: Por otro lado, parece que los teléfonos "sin hilos" existían desde hace mucho más tiempo (años 30): https://lacabezallena.com/tecnologia/asi-fue-la-primera-llamada-de-movil-de-la-historia/

Answer (score 5):

Hubiera querido hacer un comentario más que una respuesta, pero no me alcanzaban los caracteres.

Creo que la decisión de utilizar determinada terminología técnica tiene que ver con:

- las características o especificaciones del dispositivo
- cuestiones comerciales (o sea, qué suena mejor para el consumidor)

Como puede observarse en la definición de "portátil", se hace alusión a la capacidad de transporte, o sea, se asume que la cosa normalmente no era transportable. Recuerdo la vieja "radio portátil"...

"móvil" parece contraponerse a "fijo": "teléfono móvil" como opuesto de "teléfono fijo".

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo. La misma explicación vale para los computadores donde se eligió usar "computador **portátil**" y no _móvil_.